# HTML CSS Height, Color in <a> an others

Tags: html, css, colors, height

I have a small problem that is giving me a lot of headaches.

My HTML code is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Exemplo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/admin.css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="bg_menu" class="bg">
            <header class="menu_content">
                <nav id="menu">
                    <div class="wrapper_navigation">
                        <ul id="navigation" class="menu_list">
                            <li class="menu_li"><a href="#">Veículos</a>

                            </li>
                            <li class="menu_li"><a href="#">Administração</a>

                            </li>
                            <li class="menu_li"><a href="#">Newsletter</a>

                            </li>
                            <li class="menu_li"><a href="#">Estatísticas</a>

                            </li>
                            <li class="menu_li"><a href="#">Manutenção</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapper_options">
                        <ul class="menu_list">
                            <li id="li_option" class="menu_li">
                                <img id="adminPhoto" src="${admin.img}" width="40px" height="40px" alt="Foto do Administrador" />
                                <p id="adminName">${admin.fullName}</p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>

        <div id="bg_content" class="bg">
            <div class="content">

            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The CSS is:

```
 @charset "UTF-8";
    /**
     * Cascading Style Sheet - CSS
     *
     * This CSS file is responsible for reset all default browsers CSS. This action improves the control over the CSS and
     * ensures that the styles are rendered uniformly in all browsers. Based on Eric Meyer (v2.0) CSS archive with some
     * modifications.
     */

    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address,
    big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside,
    canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time,
    mark, audio, video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        outline: none;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
        display: block;
    }

    body {
        line-height: 1;
    }

    ol, ul {
        list-style: none;
    }

    blockquote, q {
        quotes: none;
    }

    blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
        content: none;
    }

    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }


    @charset "UTF-8";
    /**
     * Cascading Style Sheet - CSS
     */

    /*Formating the navigation menu, it's same on all pages, changing only the active menu item. We also have the
    formatting of the base that will receive the contents of the pages.*/

    html, body {
        font-family: "Carrois Gothic", sans-serif; color: #444; background: #EEEBEB; font-size: 16px; height: 100%;
        /*Browser webkit font fix*/
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
        /*improve the readability of the text avoiding aliasing in the fonts.*/
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased; -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -ms-font-smoothing: antialiased; font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }

    .bg { float: left; min-width: 1024px; width: 100%; }

    #bg_menu { #000; background: url('../img/bg_header.png') repeat-x; }

    #bg_content { min-height: 100%; height: auto; background: url('../img/dotted.jpg') repeat-x;
        box-shadow: inset  4px 6px 30px #969696; }

    .menu_content { height: 54px; margin: 0 auto; width: 1000px; color: #FFF; }

    .content { position: relative; width: 1000px; height: 300px; margin: 30px auto; border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: #FFF; box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #A5A8AB; }

    .wrapper_navigation { float: left; padding: 2px; }

    .wrapper_options {  float: right; padding: 0 6px 2px 6px; margin: 2px 12px 0 2px; }

    .menu_list { height: 50px; display: table-cell; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; }

    .menu_li { display: inline; padding: 16px 14px 18px 14px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 90%;  }

    #li_option { padding: 2px; }

    #adminPhoto { float: left;  }

    #adminName { float: right; max-width: 200px; }

    .menu_li a { color: #FFF; }

    #navigation .menu_li:hover, .wrapper_options:hover { background-color:#FFF; color: #000;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px #969696; }
```

I have 3 problems in code:

1º in my menu, all  elements don't obey the order of white, they obey only when put directly on the element  rule.

2º My menu has a 54px of height, because this, my body background exceeds 54px, making the scroll bar appear.

3º The `<p>` that contains the administrator name has a 200px of max-width,  but I can't center it (already tried line-height, but that does not centralize to content that may occupy more than one line).

**I tried to do this three days ago, but I can't do this. I appreciate those who help me.**

Sorry my bad English, I'm improving my skills in English the very short time ago.

Answer (score 2):

```
#bg_menu { #000;
```

This css is incorrect. I assume you mean:

```
#bg_menu { background-color: #000;
```

Comment: Yes yes, sorry sorry, I added a color because I can't send all background images to test. change color if you need.

Comment: You should post your EXACT code, not change it before posting. Of course we won't have your images, but we can substitute our own if necessary. However, create a page in jsFiddle (or other) to make it easier for someone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the color declaration on the `<a>` itself, not on the `<li>`:

```
#navigation .menu_li:hover a {color: #000;}
```

Regarding the height problem, just remove all height settings. Avoid setting heights. It just causes problems. A better alternative is to set the `li`s to `display: inline-block` and give them a line-height of 54px.

Regarding the `p`, change it to a `span` and set the image to `vertical-align: middle`.

EDIT: Here is an example of the changes: http://jsfiddle.net/n5VWn/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address,
    big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside,
    canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time,
    mark, audio, video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        outline: none;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
        display: block; overflow: hidden;
    }

    body {
        line-height: 1;
    }

    ol, ul {
        list-style: none;
    }

    blockquote, q {
        quotes: none;
    }

    blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
        content: none;
    }

    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }


    @charset "UTF-8";
    /**
     * Cascading Style Sheet - CSS
     */

    /*Formating the navigation menu, it's same on all pages, changing only the active menu item. We also have the
    formatting of the base that will receive the contents of the pages.*/

    html, body {
        font-family: "Carrois Gothic", sans-serif; color: #444; background: #EEEBEB; font-size: 16px; height: 100%;
        /*Browser webkit font fix*/
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
        /*improve the readability of the text avoiding aliasing in the fonts.*/
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased; -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -ms-font-smoothing: antialiased; font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }

    .bg { float: left; min-width: 1024px; width: 100%; }

    #bg_menu { #000; background: url('../img/bg_header.png') repeat-x; }

    #bg_content { min-height: 100%; height: auto; background: url('../img/dotted.jpg') repeat-x;
        box-shadow: inset  4px 6px 30px #969696; }

    .menu_content {margin: 0 auto; width: 1000px; color: #FFF; }

    .content { position: relative; width: 1000px; height: 300px; margin: 30px auto; border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: #FFF; box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #A5A8AB; }

    .wrapper_navigation { float: left;  }

    .wrapper_options {  float: right; display: table; padding: 0 6px 0 6px; margin: 7px 12px 0 2px; }
    .wrapper_options p, .wrapper_options img { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;}

    .menu_list { display: table; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; }

    .menu_li { display: inline-block; line-height: 54px; padding: 0 14px 0 14px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 90%;  }

    #li_option { padding: 2px; }

    #adminPhoto { }

    #adminName {  max-width: 200px; }

    .menu_li a { color: #FFF; }

    #navigation .menu_li:hover a {color: #000;}

    #navigation .menu_li:hover, .wrapper_options:hover { background-color:#FFF; color: #000;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px #969696; }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="bg_menu" class="bg">
            <header class="menu_content">
                <nav id="menu">
                    <div class="wrapper_navigation">
                        <ul id="navigation" class="menu_list">
                            <li class="menu_li"><a href="#">Veículos</a>

                            </li>
                            <li class="menu_li"><a href="#">Administração</a>

                            </li>
                            <li class="menu_li"><a href="#">Newsletter</a>

                            </li>
                            <li class="menu_li"><a href="#">Estatísticas</a>

                            </li>
                            <li class="menu_li"><a href="#">Manutenção</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapper_options">

                                <img id="adminPhoto" src="${admin.img}" width="40px" height="40px" alt="Foto do Administrador" />
                                <p id="adminName">${admin.fullName}</p>

                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>

        <div id="bg_content" class="bg">
            <div class="content">

            </div>

        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had already done that. But the rule, I could put color in the menu div and all catch from him, like administratorname grabs!

Comment: Another problem is: when I put the mouse over the <li> it will not change to black.

Comment: `I could put color in the menu div and all catch from him` - no, the color setting on the `a` will override that. Make the change I suggested and then if there are other problems, work from there. It worked fine for me.

Comment: Sorry Ralph, I had put it before, and should have put later #navigation .menu_li:hover, .wrapper_options:hover { ... }.  Worked properly. Still exist then the other two errors I mentioned. Forgive me for the silly mistake of color, was really lack of my attention, I had already done that.

Comment: Tks ralph. I made the changes, centralized name (if I just change to make span and vertical-align: middle does not work.), but I need to remove all padding and margins? because when I changed only the heights, the menu was huge.

Comment: Ralph, sorry for the delay. I needed solve a problem and I stayed away from the computer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tips. Maybe I need to change the option div, because they will have a drop down menu, and I'll need the <ul> was taken. The only remaining problem would be the height, which also do not know to solve.  Even removing the heights on divs, notice that the div bg_content, passes 54px down (making the scroll bar appears). I do not know if I can do (validly) 100%-54px. But, I believe it is very inelegant.